# How do I remove an A record with the Plesk command line utility?

Tags: linux

I'm trying the following

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/dns -d domain.tld -a sub.domain.tld -ip 127.0.0.1
```

Getting the error:

> Unable del record in DNS server: unable find DNS record

But in the zone file I have

```
sub.domain.tld.           IN A    127.0.0.1
```

(note: dns/IP obfuscated for customer privacy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known problem with `dns.sh`. Solution here: [KB9406](http://kb.parallels.com/en/9406)
Download this fix: [fix.zip](http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/14644/Attachments/fix.zip) and place the file `cuDns.php`in `/usr/local/psa/admin/plib/api-common/`

Comment: so my syntax is right? this is just a bug in the program... which of course my supervisor won't let me patch to fix.

Comment: Sure. More info: http://download1.swsoft.com/Plesk/Plesk8.2/Doc/plesk-8.2-unix-cli/37771.htm